# Can't seem to override CreateController in the DefaultControllerFactory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, logging, elmah

I'm trying to implement Elmah into my MVC application using this great tutorial.

http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/logging-on-mvc-part-1/

Everything seems fine, but when I build, I get

> no suitable method found to override

Below is the class I took right from the sample

```
public class ErrorHandlingControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Injects a custom attribute 
        /// on every action that is invoked by the controller
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="requestContext">The request context</param>
        /// <param name="controllerName">The name of the controller</param>
        /// <returns>An instance of a controller</returns>
        public override IController CreateController(
            RequestContext requestContext,
            string controllerName)
        {
            var controller =
                base.CreateController(requestContext,
                controllerName);

            var c = controller as Controller;

            if (c != null)
            {
                c.ActionInvoker =
                    new ErrorHandlingActionInvoker(
                        new HandleErrorWithELMAHAttribute());
            }

            return controller;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I move this to the default MVC project in my solution it seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after much more research, I found the issue from this link

http://forums.asp.net/t/1622810.aspx

Needed to add a reference to System.Web.Routing since it was in a seperate project.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build successfully:

1. Created a new Empty ASP.NET MVC 2 project
2. From the tutorial, copied in the code for the `HandleErrorWithELMAHAttribute` class.
3. Copied the code for the `ErrorHandlingActionInvoker` class.
4. Copied the code for the `ErrorHandlingControllerFactory` class.
5. Added necessary `using` statements and a reference to ELMAH.

Then, to check, I replaced the original code for the `ErrorHandlingControllerFactory` with the code from your question, and it also compiled without error.

I was able to get that error was by adding a class named `DefaultControllerFactory` so that `ErrorHandlingControllerFactory` would be inheriting from that.  It seems unlikely, but you may want to make sure you are inheriting from the correct class.

Comment: Thanks adrift.  Seems to be inheriting correctly.  Intellisense says my DefaultControllerFactory is the System.Web.MVC one.  I double checked my version of System.Web.MVC as well, seems ok (MVC 2)  The only thing different I am doing is sticking all these classes in it's own project which shouldn't matter from what I understand.